# error 'index out of bound' for iris diagnosis matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

i'm doing the iris diagnosis using matlab with GUI. as i start run my coding, it shows the error saying "Attempted to access circleiris(2); index out of bounds because numel(circleiris)=1."

```
Error in IRISDIAGNOSIS>pushbutton2_Callback (line 501)
[x,y] = circlecoords([circleiris(2),circleiris(1)],circleiris(3),size(eyeimage));
```

this is the coding for this error

```
%create accumulator for pixel location
imgsize = size(eyeimage);
l1 = zeros([imgsize(1), imgsize(2)]);  
l2 = zeros([imgsize(1), imgsize(2)]);
l3 = zeros([imgsize(1), imgsize(2)]);
l4 = zeros([imgsize(1), imgsize(2)]);

 %get pixel coords for circle around iris
[x,y]   =circlecoords([circleiris(2),circleiris(1)],circleiris(3),size(eyeimage));
ind2 = sub2ind(size(imagewithcircles),double(y),double(x));

%get pixel coords for circle around pupil
[xp, yp] =   circlecoords([circlepupil(2),circlepupil(1)],circlepupil(3),size(eyeimage));
ind1 = sub2ind(size(imagewithcircles), double(yp), double(xp));


[xc, yc] = segmentcircle([circle1(2), circle1(1)], circle1(3), size(eyeimage));
ind3 = sub2ind(size(imagewithcircles), double(yc), double(xc));


[xd, yd] = segmentcircle([circle2(2), circle2(1)], circle2(3),  size(eyeimage));
ind4 = sub2ind(size(imagewithcircles), double(yd), double(xd));
```

this is the function of the segmentiris

```
 function [circleiris, circlepupil, irl, iru, icl, icu, circle1, circle2] = segmentiris(eyeimage)

 % define range of pupil & iris radii

%CASIA
lpupilradius = 28;
upupilradius = 75;
lirisradius = 80;
uirisradius = 150;



 % define scaling factor to speed up Hough transform
 scaling = 0.4;

reflecthres = 240;

 % find the iris boundary
[row, col, r] = findcircle(eyeimage, lirisradius, uirisradius, scaling, 2,   0.20, 0.19, 1.00, 0.00);

circleiris = [row col r];

rowd = double(row);
cold = double(col);
rd = double(r);

irl = round(rowd-rd);
iru = round(rowd+rd);
icl = round(cold-rd);
icu = round(cold+rd);

imgsize = size(eyeimage);

if irl < 1 
irl = 1;
end


if icl < 1
icl = 1;
end


if iru > imgsize(1)
iru = imgsize(1);
end


if icu > imgsize(2)
icu = imgsize(2);
end

% to find the inner pupil, use just the region within the previously
% detected iris boundary
imagepupil = eyeimage(irl:iru,icl:icu);

%find pupil boundary
[rowp, colp, r] = findcircle(imagepupil, lpupilradius, upupilradius ,0.6,2,0.25,0.25,1.00,1.00);

rowp = double(rowp);
colp = double(colp);
r = double(r);

row = double(irl) + rowp;
col = double(icl) + colp;

row = round(row);
col = round(col);
r1 = 1/3 *(rd - r);
r2 = 2/3 * (rd - r);
rnew1 = r1 + r;
rnew2 = r2 + r;

circlepupil = [row, col, r];
circle1 = [row, col, rnew1];
circle2 = [row, col, rnew2];
```

anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to make it reasonably answerable.

Comment: i already edit my question. can u guys understand it? hope u can help me..

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  `circleiris` in your code is expected to have two elements but it only has 1.  Please give more information on how `circleiris` is populated.  Right now I can't suggest anything on how to fix your problem because I don't know where `circleiris` comes from or how it gets set.

Comment: i add the segmentiris func.. is that where the circleiris is populated?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the circleiris array does not have index 2. In the code you've posted, you're calling `circleiris(2)`. You can insert `display(circleiris);` just before this line: `%get pixel coords for circle around iris` to see what the circleiris array looks like (size and values).

Comment: it said the circleiris size is 20.. then what should i do @Pieter12345.. sorry i'm new in matlab..

Comment: Above line 501 (where the error occured) insert this: 'disp(strcat('Size of circleiris = ', numel(circleiris)))'. If the size was 20 at that point, the error you posted should not occur at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right here:

```
% find the iris boundary
[row, col, r] = findcircle(eyeimage, lirisradius, uirisradius, scaling, 2,   0.20, 0.19, 1.00, 0.00);

circleiris = [row col r];
```

We don't have access to `findcircle`, but I'm assuming that it's performing some sort of Circular Hough Transform.  `circleiris` is supposed to be three elements, but if what I suspect of your `findcircle` function is true, this means that the parameters you are choosing renders `row` and `col` to be empty, and so doing `circleiris = [row col r]` makes `circleiris` be of length 1.  After this point, your script assumes that `circleiris` is of length 3, but you are getting an out of bounds error because `circleiris` is only of length 1 most likely due to `row` and `col` being empty.  I would suggest putting in a debug statement right after the `findcircle` function, or doing `disp([row col])` and see what you get for this output.  I suspect that it will be empty.

Therefore, you should try and change the parameters of this function until you get good results.  Judging from your language in the comments, you probably didn't write the code you showed us, so ask whoever you got it from on some advice on how to vary the parameters to suit your application.

---

Good luck!